# Appending URL subdomain as URL path in HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, rewrite, reverse-proxy, haproxy, url-routing

I want to convert following URL:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/a/b/c
```

To this:

```
http://example.com/subdomain/a/b/c
```

In HAProxy.
Thanks a lot